# Shopify App proxy showing "502 Bad Gateway" issue

Tags: shopify, http-proxy

I am trying to set shopify app proxy url. Although It was working fine before few days back but suddenly I am getting error "502 Bad Gateway".On the store page, it is showing message "There was an error in the third-party application". I also tried to test with different servers and have used both one by one "http" and "https" but I am getting same kind of error in all cases. Please suggest how to set shopify proxy url from shopify developer account. Below are test links:

https://dummy.sdnadev.com/test.html

And I tried to set proxy as :

http://dee1-11.myshopify.com/apps/PG-2C2P

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It not supporting subdomain. When I use full domain , it works with me.

Answer (score 0):

`Bad Gateway` error in shopify is often caused when doing large **POST** or **PUT** that take **longer than 90 seconds**.